# Not able to edit Task 'Assigned To' field when displayed as table in VF page

Tags: visualforce, tasks, pageblocktable, inline

I have created a Record Type for Task called 'Follow on Task'. In a VF page I am displaying all 'Follow on Task' records in a apex:pageBlockTable with mode='inlineEdit'

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="COBContactDetailController" >
<apex:form id="followontaskform">
<apex:pageBlock title="Follow on Tasks' mode=" inlineEdit " id="followontasks">
    <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
        <apex:commandButton value="New Follow on Tasks" action="{!addFollowonTask}" rerender="followontasks" />
        ...
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    <apex:outputPanel layout="block" styleClass="scroll">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!followontasks}" var="followontask" id="followontaskTable" styleclass="floatingHeaderTable">
            <apex:column title="Subject" value="{!followontask.Subject}" />
            <apex:column title="ActivityDate" value="{!followontask.ActivityDate}" />
            <apex:column title="Status" value="{!followontask.Status}" />
            <apex:column title="Related To" value="{!followontask.WhatId}" />
            <apex:column title="Assigend To" value="{!followontask.OwnerId}" />
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

I am able to edit data in all columns but 'Assogned To'(OwnerId) is not editable. It is actually a default field of type Lookup(User,Queue). But if I edit/create it in its own tab it is I am able to look up and select different users in 'Assogned To' field . Am I missing anything. I really have make it editable in the VF page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't missing anything - the owner id doesn't support inline editing either in Visualforce or the regular UI for any sobject type.

Its not the polymorphic nature of the relationship, as you can inline edit the whatid and choose the object type before accessing the lookup.

This isn't documented anywhere (that I can find), but there is an idea on the ideaexchange to add this functionality:

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bp6WAAS